# toString() defined on private members of abstract class,then why printing subclass object prints along with private members of abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class absclass {

private int x,y;
public absclass(int x,int y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String(x+" --------- "+y);
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class pc extends absclass {

    public pc(int x,int y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(x, y);
//      x=x;
//      y=y;
    }

    public void compute()
    {
        System.out.println("well this is pc");
        System.out.println(this);
        //for y=1;
    }
```

Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new pc(0, 2).compute();
}
```

Why does the **subclass** **pc** have access to the private members **x,y** of the **abstract class**? Based on inheritance rules any private members in the parent class are not inherited into the childclass so the childclass shouldn't have any members x,y. Yet the output is:

> 0 --------- 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pc` doesn't have access to `x` and `y`. It has access to `toString()`, because that's a public method. And `toString()` has access to `x` and `y`, because it's defined in `absclass`.

Comment: what happens to be argument of the subclass object passed initially to the println()? Consider A,B,C classes C inherits from B and B from A.   If C,B don't override toString() will A's toString() be called everytime B or C object is printed?

Comment: @yolob21 Yes, of course. What else should be called?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, for the same set of classes and the same hierarchy of inheritance as above in my comment   if A,B override toString() and C doesn't, which will be called?

Comment: @yolob21 The one of `B`. Always the one highest up in the hierarchy. If `C` inherits `B`, it inherits all of `B`'s methods, _except those it overrides_. Same goes for `B` inheriting `A`. So `B` inherits `A`, but overrides `toString()`, `C` inherits `B` and doesn't override `toString()`, hence `B` and `C` have `B`'s `toString()`.

Answer (score 3):

It does not. `toString()` is inherited from the parent class. Since you have not overriden this method in the sub class and as it has access to the private variables of parent class, when println is called, it simply prints the the output from parent class `toString()`.

Comment: but I am printing the subclass object,then why does toString() get invoked on parent class with its private members?

Comment: Because your subclass doesn't override toString(), what else should it call?

Comment: Even though the subclass does not override `toString()`, it has the public methods of parent class and hence the one overridden in the parent class is called.

Comment: what happens to be argument of the subclass object passed initially to the println()?

Comment: @yolob21 _"what happens to be argument of the subclass object passed initially to the println()?"_ Could you rephrase that question? I am unsure what you're asking, might be a language thing, English isn't my first language.

Comment: @MaxVollmer added a comment to your answer

Comment: Basically, `println()` calls `toString()` of the object passed to it and your sub class `toString()` prints what you have shown in the output. Note that the keyword `this` refers to the current object ie. the object on which `compute()` is called.